# How to position ::after background image into the center of the div?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to position the logo to the center of the header div with half of the logo overflowing to the bottom div. I have the following but I can't figure out how to dynamically set it to be centered. Because relying on `top` and `left` values seems like it's going to be inconsistent.

```
.header {
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #000;

    &:after {
        z-index: 2;
        content: ' ';
        position: absolute;
        left: 27%;
        top: 60%;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-image: url('images/logo.png');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `left: 50%` with negative `margin-left` (half of logo width).

```css
.header {
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}

.header:after {
  margin-left: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #f00;
  bottom: -100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  content: ' ';
  z-index: 2;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest flexbox?

Centering logic will be handled for you, then you just need to make sure the background image is positioned correctly.

```
.header {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;

    &:after {
        content: '';
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        background: url('http://i.imgur.com/9My4X1v.jpg');
        background-size: auto 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/JackHasaKeyboard/9azLwx22/10/